# How to create ad slots in wordpress not by using direct plug-in?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, adsense, ads

I have just started a new site for students to help them for their final year projects

and i have applied for google adsense for that then i have added the adsense code to my site post but its related to post only when i post the another content it goes down and i dont want to implement plug in so plz tell me how to edit the wordpress theme and i just want to put the ad on the top (inline ad).

my [site](http://www.wantprojects.com) :

Answer (score 0):

try this - go to header.php file in code editor, and insert adsense code right there,
for exemple in header class or smth like this(there are usually comments there, to help you find where header is)